# Modelling static class variables in UML

Tags: uml

does anybody know how to model this Java class in UML:

```
public class Picture {
public static Picture picture = Picture.load();

}
```

I am not really sure if I should model the static variable picture as a association of Picture with itself or in some other way. Does anybody know how to model this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The variable could be model simply as a UML property.

Regards,

EBR